# How can we bind a kendo grid with kendo autocomplete textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-grid

I have a text box and kendo grid on my page.
On writing text on the textbox I want to filter grid content.
I googled and found that it is possible by Autocomplete.
How can I bind my kendo grid with autocomplete textbox

Comment: There are definitely ways to do this. Please add what you have tried so we can help you out. In addition, you seem to not have accepted any answers for your past question. Please make sure you accept the one that helped you the most. Thanks.

Comment: @gitsitgo I am new to MVC and kendo so I just know the approach for the above scenario thats why I have not started coding. And in for past questions most of the time the answers did not work out for me so I was not replying.

Comment: If you know the approach, you can start coding. Basically, you want to store your grid datasource data in an array, set that as a datasource for your autocomplete box. On the changed event of the autocomplete box, you then want to filter the grid datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You can find one way on how to do it at [How to have an autocomplete field inside kendoUI grid using asp.net mvc wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864249/how-to-have-an-autocomplete-field-inside-kendoui-grid-using-asp-net-mvc-wrapper/24374450#24374450).  Basically you will have to create EditorTemplate and reference it from grid.

Hope this helps.